# How Lerp Scale and Lerp Position GameObject In Unity Same Time On Specific Position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to lerp scale and lerp position GameObject in Unity in same time with this part of code, but gameobject scale first then set up the position.

```
    iTween.ScaleTo(gameObject, Scale, 1f);
    transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, positionToMoveTo, 1);
```

Also I try with this:

```
IEnumerator LerpPosition(Vector3 targetPosition, float duration)
{
    // startPosition = transform.position;
    while (time < duration)
    {
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, targetPosition, time / duration);
        transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localScale, Scale, time / duration);

        time += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    transform.position = targetPosition;
}
```

but I got same result.

Actually I need to zoom in on specific point of 2D sprite with these codes like in image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7C2J.jpg)

Any help please?

Comment: Create a variable for the start scale, otherwise you are constantly changing the start scale.  The first code doesn't make sense since lerp interpolates based on the value of t, which is always 1 in that line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, positionToMoveTo, 1);
```

means ignore the `startPosition` and immediately jump to the `positionToMoveTo`. In general I would not merge tween with Coroutines, decide for either one of them.

In your other attempt there are also few odd things

- You need to store the `startPosition` and `startScale`
- You once use `localPosition` but in the start and end switch to `position` (= absolute world space) which might of course be quite different

So something like e.g.

```
IEnumerator LerpPositionAndScale(Vector3 targetLocalPosition, Vector3 targetLocalScale, float duration)
{
    var startPosition = transform.localPosition;
    var startScale = transfor.localScale;

    for(var timePassed = 0f; timePassed < duration; timePassed += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        var factor = timePassed / duration;
        // [optional] add ease-in and -out
        factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);

        transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, targetLocalPosition, factor);
        transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScale, targetLocalScale, factor);

        yield return null;
    }

    transform.localPosition = targetLocalPosition;
    transform.localScale = targetLocalScale;
}
```